# C udp application simulate packet loss

Tags: c, sockets, udp, packet

I have udp server-client application written in C. On the client side packet loss is detected using recvfrom function and sequence numbers of packets. How can I now simulate dropped packet's on the client side, for example if server is sending 1000 packet I want to drop 20% of them? I want to do this in the code, not for example using ip tables or something like that. And one more thing, I have few clients and I want that they can dropped different packets, not the same one.

```
while(1){

    nbytes = recvfrom(socket, buffer, MAX_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &srv_addr, &addrlen);

        if (nbytes != -1) {

    // packet is received

        }else{

    //packet is not received

        }

}
```

Comment: You could do this using Wanem without any coding on your part at all - http://wanem.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I don't want any emulators but solution in my code above. Thx anyway

Comment: All you're going to do from *your* code, is receive and then not-parse the packet. If you actually want to *drop* the packet you have to do it from kernel level, or stick something like wanem in between. Wanem is easy to use and allows full testing of your network code, in more than just the scenario you give.

Comment: I now that I have to receive and then not-parse the packet. But I'm not sure how can I do that in the code using also probabilities and condition that different packets must be dropped at different clients ? (I don't need to drop the packet from the kernel level)